# Python Mysql executemany update statement slow/application stops

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I am parsing a text file and then updating a mysql table column with the values parsed from the file based on the primary key in this table. I was using sqlite to do this initially and writing to a local sqlite file where I didn't run in to any issues. Now I'm writing to a new mysql db and when using executemany to update the table with large lists parsed from the text file the updates take a long time sometimes 20 - 30 seconds and in some cases where the list has ~50k entries the application never successfully writes anything.

I've tried using executemany as this seemed to alleviate any performance issues when using sqlite, the code will stop working once a large enough list is used in the executemany call. From what I've read I should use executemany with INSERT and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but this produces a truncated data error.

```
def strip_file(x):
        filePath = 'somefile.txt'
        with open(filePath) as file:
                        for i, line in enumerate(file):
                                if i > x:
                                        indicatorName = re.findall(re.escape('some text')+"(.*?)"+re.escape("blah"),line)
                                        if indicatorName:
                                                indicatorCount = re.findall(re.escape('number')+"(.*?)"+re.escape("|"),line)
                                                indicatorTime = re.findall(re.escape('time')+"(.*?)"+re.escape('end'),line)
                                                for i in indicatorTime:
                                                        i.strip()

                                                indicatorName = re.findall(re.escape('ending' + indicatorCount[0] +'|')+"(.*?)"+re.escape('|'),line)
                                                indicatorNameInd = indicatorName[0].split(",")
                                                indicatorNameInd = filter(None, indicatorNameInd)
                                                for i in indicatorNameInd:
                                                        i.strip()
                                                indicatorTimeSeq = [indicatorTime]*len(indicatorNameInd)
                                                indicatorTimeList = list(chain(*indicatorTimeSeq))


                                                indicatorSeq = zip(indicatorTimeList, indicatorNameInd)




                                                cursor.execute('SET autocommit=0')
                                                sql = 'UPDATE IndicatorData SET IndicatorTime=%s WHERE IndicatorID=%s'
                                                cursor.executemany(sql, indicatorSeq)
                                                conn.commit()
```

This approach will stop writing if the indicator seq is large.

Using INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE:

```
                                   sql = 'INSERT INTO IndicatorData (IndID, IndTime) VALUES (%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VALUES IndTime = %s'
                                        cursor.executemany(sql, indicatorSeq)
```

I expect the IndTime in the table to update if the IndicatorID associated in the list is present in the IndID column. Instead I get this error:

ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Comment: IndicatorSeq has only  2 values, and you need 3 for your query, because there are 3 placeholders.

Comment: insert on duplicate key update should only have 2 placeholders for the values in IndID and IndTime and if IndID is already there IndTime should be updated.

I could be wrong, but that's the way I understood the documentation.

Comment: You are wrong, if you use 3 placeholders, you need 3 values. You didn' t understand the doc

Comment: I updated IndicatorSeq to have 3 values and receive the same error

Comment: Try to do a print of indicatorSeq to see what you have in there ...

Comment: Printed and it is what I expect.... [('12345678', '16:45:01 ', '16:45:01 '), ('23456789',  '16:45:01 ', '16:45:01 ')...etc